# Restrict mouse within an area

Tags: python, scripting

With python script is it possible to restrict the mouse within an area, like Object->Transform->Move menu does in 3d viewport? When this op is started, user can't move the mouse cursor out of the 3d viewport.

Comment: Why? What is your overall goal?

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/91900/how-to-get-the-mouse-position-outside-of-the-window-on-modal-operator  AFAIK there is no option in blender python to control the mouse location (get sure, not set).. Would require some third party tool perhaps.

Comment: @Leander I have a script that starts drawing on first mouse click and finishes on second click (just like move op , which finishes after second click). So the user should not be able to move the cursor out of the viewport between the two clicks.

Comment: Why is the drawing position/"brush" not always under the mouse position? Is it similiar to the moving op with Shift? You know that a modal operator will capture the mouse position in other regions/areas as well?

Comment: @batFINGER Thank you for the pointer. I wish this was possible :(

Comment: (I apologize for being so forward. Most of the time, hijacking the mouse is a design fault with better alternatives.)

Comment: If the user can only draw in the region with the mouse, they are not going to move it outside of said region.

Comment: @Leander I understand it's better to not curtail user freedom as much as possible. It would be possible to draw without any restriction if the drawing were to be done with dragging the mouse (press to start, move to draw, release to finish). But unfortunately my requierment is to start drawing after the click (press+release), continue with it (move) till next click (again press+release). So between the first and second click if I allow user to click anywhere, my drawing could go haywire, if user starts a new op in the middle.

Comment: You could run a modal operator, that only exits correctly if the second/next click is in the same region. You can check the region of the 2nd click; if it is outside of the region, you can abort thr operation.

Comment: This would also prevent other operations from running simultaneously.

Comment: @Leander Yes, maybe. But then there is another problem. I need to catch the mouse press event in the modal function. If I let the other operations in the queue process the press event after me (by returning PASS_THROUGH) then there are some undesirable results like objects in the viewport moving with the mouse press (which was for drawing). And if I dont let the other ops to process the press event (by returning RUNNING_MODAL) then users can't use any buttons on the header or toolbar.

Comment: @Leander So my idea was restrict the user within the drawable area, and return RUNNING_MODAL on press. The mouse will be freed up only after user cancels the operation.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, I have the feeling that this is already much closer to the actual problem your facing. In your description, the user can only exit the drawing space (to execute other commands) if he cancels the operation. Inverse, you could design it, that leaving the drawing space cancels the operation, right?

Comment: User can potentially leave the drawing space quite often. And I can't cancel the op immediately as user leaves the space (even when he is not drawing since the drawing op is active.)